# importing aar file in flutter project

Tags: android, flutter, aar, flutter-plugin, flutter-packages

i want to create a aar file [which takes two inputs a and b and returns the sum of the values], now i want to use that aar file in my flutter project and i will give inputs [a and b] from flutter UI and i need to display the sum of value in flutter UI ?

i have tried but getting some errors in communicating between aar and flutter  !

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@label value=(aar_methods) from (unknown)
> is also present at [:com.example.addaar-addition-1.0.0:] AndroidManifest.xml:15:9-41 value=(@string/app_name).
> Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:label"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:4:5-35:19 to override.

i have tried adding this suggestion ,then i got

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.

> com.android.manifmerger.ManifestMerger2$MergeFailureException: Error parsing /home/santosh/VsCode/sample/aar_methods/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

this error

Answer (score 0):

try to add this line to the manifest node in your main manifest file.

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).